# Nested Type of Template not depending on Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, nested-types

I've been struggeling with the following problem:

```cpp
// this is in a header file
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    T x, y;
    // ... other stuff

    struct Bar {
        int a, b;
        // ... other stuff
        void f() const;
    };

    Bar h() const
    { return { reinterpret_cast<int>(this->x), reinterpret_cast<int>(this->y) }; }
};
```

It's clear that `Foo::h()` needs to be implemented in the header file since it depends on the template argument.
But this is not the case for `Foo::Bar::f()`.
I would like to implement this in a separate .cpp-file, since it only needs to compile once and so on.

Just as a note: I would like to keep this as a nested type for namespacing reasons.

Is there a nice way to do this ?
I dont't see why this shouldn't work, since `Foo::Bar` does not depend on the template argument at all.

Thank you very much !

Edit: fixed typo

Comment: `Foo<int>::Bar` is not the same as `Foo<char>::Bar`, all of them need a definition...

Comment: *"It's clear that `Foo::g()`"*. there are no `g()` in above code.

Comment: everything inside `Foo` depends on `T`. really everything. There can be a specialization eg for `T = int`:  `template <> Foo<int> {};`

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, I see that, but on the other hand, the implementation does not depend on that. So why is there a need to compile this multiple times ? I mean if this is a language limitation I'm going with it, but I see some potential to optimize this.
and oops typo :3

Comment: the "nice way" is to only place stuff inside `Foo` that should depend on `T` the rest not. You can for example consider to inherit from a nontemplate base class

Answer (score 2):

> I dont't see why this shouldn't work, since Foo::Bar does not depend on the template argument at all

This is not correct conclusion - the nested class has access to all names (private, protected, etc) to which the enclosing class has access, so depending on how the enclosing class is instantiated, the nested class has different surrounding context, thus `Foo<int>::Bar` and `Foo<char>::Bar` are not the same classes (to be precise - the nested class is part of the enclosing class definition, so without `Foo<int>`/`Foo<char>`, `Bar` doesn't exist, but since these are different classes, `Bar` under those classes are also different)

Comment: thanks ! fair point, at compile time the types cannot be known, therefore a symbol-table doesn't make sense (although it isn't used)

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean by "namespacing reasons", but if you just want to access it like `Foo<T>::Bar`, you can use alias.

```
struct ChocolateBar {
    int a, b;
    // ... other stuff
    void f() const;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    T x, y;
    // ... 
    using Bar = ::ChocolateBar;
    Bar h() const { return { reinterpret_cast<int>(this->x), reinterpret_cast<int>(this->y) }; }
};
```

Comment: What I meant with "namespacing reasons" was that I wanted to be able to use the name `Bar` somewhere else too

Comment: @IuppiterZeus you don't need to name outer class `Bar`, or you can put it inside another namespace.